# Can I recover the titanite/petrified dragon bone from unused gear?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I've got various bits of unused armour and weapons I upgraded with titanite and petrified dragon bone. Can I somehow recover the titanite and petrified dragon bone from these items to use on other things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Luckily, as you progress in the game there are vendors who will sell all items to you.

Here [is a link](http://www.tradeindetectives.com/blog/dark-souls-2-titanite-shard-locations-487/) that explains where you can purchase these items in the game.  Once you get rolling, it's not that difficult to obtain the necessary souls to buy as many of these as you want.